# php, xml outputting entire values from tags with different attributes

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm trying to make an application which outputs the entire images from an xml file. The images are stored in different img tags with different attributes . etc.. here's the xml page..

```
<issue>
    <coverImage id="13088328">
    0mjg7sd8q8tjk63z93p7</coverImage>
<cover>
</cover>
<page template="rowpicrowpic">
    <img id="13088334">
    wqqkrnt74l18p9nxnyf2</img>
<img id="13088364">
    fjm6cjtpxvc2t2wjcbc6</img>
</page>
<page template="pics4">
    <img id="13088373">
    nc753vx8bkt7195nz8zs</img>
<img id="13088379">
    rz7c5tkzm8mcxcfnbrch</img>
<img id="13088379">
    rz7c5tkzm8mcxcfnbrch</img>
<img id="13088373">
    nc753vx8bkt7195nz8zs</img>
</page>
<page template="rowpicrow2text">
    <txt>
</txt>
<txt>
</txt>
<img id="13098696">
    h8b6cpjmyjp344rsyzwq</img>
</page>
<page template="rowpictextrowpic">
    <txt>
        test
</txt>
<img id="13088373">
    nc753vx8bkt7195nz8zs</img>
<img id="13088334">
    wqqkrnt74l18p9nxnyf2</img>
</page>
<page template="rowtextrowpic">
    <txt>
    <![CDATA[]]>
</txt>
<img id="13085748">
    zhs2q9z92jk98yjgnhrc</img>
</page>
<page template="rowpictextrowpic">
    <txt>
    <![CDATA[]]>
</txt>
<img id="13088379">
    rz7c5tkzm8mcxcfnbrch</img>
<img id="13085727">
    nbshpr8z9mlzth9n0lt1</img>
</page>
<page template="double">
    <img id="13085697">
    vw5dnsjqs6sxvbz9z22n</img>
</page>
<page template="empty">
</page>
<page template="double">
    <img id="13098702">
    kx1hyh88jy4xdb6mqbvd</img>
</page>
<page template="empty">
</page>
<page template="onepage">
    <img id="13088400">
    159zngkbftmztzcgr013</img>
</page>
</issue>
```

What i'm trying to do it have all of the img values such as
0mjg7sd8q8tjk63z93p7,
wqqkrnt74l18p9nxnyf2,
fjm6cjtpxvc2t2wjcbc6,
nc753vx8bkt7195nz8zs,
rz7c5tkzm8mcxcfnbrch,
and nc753vx8bkt7195nz8zs
to be outputted onto a page.. I have tried to do this this way but I'm trying to do it a different way and not manually writing the path to the image.

```
echo "Image1: <img src='http://image-link.com/".$xmlfile->page[0]->img[1].".jpg'/>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use simplexml object and xpath to get list of all images in xml

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
foreach($xml->xpath('//img|coverImage') as $img) 
    echo trim($img) ."\n";
```

**[demo](https://eval.in/607275)**